# When I specify x has type a, why does Haskell try to infer it has type a0?

Tags: haskell, types

Sometimes I'll specify something's type in a signature as, say, `a`, and GHC will respond that it can't deduce that its type is `a0`. Is there a single reason this happens, or a number of different possible reasons? Sometimes I solve it, sometimes not; I'm hoping for a unified theory.

Here's a short example. (To see this code including comments explaining what it's trying to do, see [here](https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/vivid/blob/dac2d120395c1d96266e5d24632e324d8b335be9/learning/riddles/gadt-forget/closest-to-vivid.hs).)

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses
           , AllowAmbiguousTypes
           , FlexibleInstances
           , GADTs #-}

type SynthName = String

data Synth format where
  Synth :: SynthName -> Synth format

data MessageA format where
  MessageA :: String -> MessageA format
data MessageB format where
  MessageB :: String -> MessageB format

class (Message format) a where
  theMessage :: a -> String
instance (Message format) (MessageA format) where
  theMessage (MessageA msg) = msg
instance (Message format) (MessageB format) where
  theMessage (MessageB msg) = msg

play :: Message format m => Synth format -> m -> IO ()
play (Synth name) msg =
  print $ name ++ " now sounds like " ++ theMessage msg
```

That produces the following error.

```
riddles/gadt-forget/closest-to-vivid.hs:38:42: error:
    • Could not deduce (Message format0 m)
        arising from a use of ‘theMessage’
      from the context: Message format m
        bound by the type signature for:
                   play :: forall format m.
                           Message format m =>
                           Synth format -> m -> IO ()
        at riddles/gadt-forget/closest-to-vivid.hs:36:1-54
      The type variable ‘format0’ is ambiguous
      Relevant bindings include
        msg :: m (bound at riddles/gadt-forget/closest-to-vivid.hs:37:19)
        play :: Synth format -> m -> IO ()
          (bound at riddles/gadt-forget/closest-to-vivid.hs:37:1)
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Message format (MessageA format)
          -- Defined at riddles/gadt-forget/closest-to-vivid.hs:30:10
        instance Message format (MessageB format)
          -- Defined at riddles/gadt-forget/closest-to-vivid.hs:32:10
    • In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘theMessage msg’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
        ‘" now sounds like " ++ theMessage msg’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘name ++ " now sounds like " ++ theMessage msg’
   |
38 |   print $ name ++ " now sounds like " ++ theMessage msg
```

Answer (score 6):

`Message` is a multi-parameter typeclass.  In order to determine which instance to use, there needs to be a concrete choice for `a` *and* for `format`.  However, the method

```
theMessage :: a -> String
```

doesn't even mention `format`, so we have no way of figuring out which concrete type to use to find an instance of `Message`.  The ambiguous type error you presumably got was about this (but that can be a tricky error message, I don't blame you for just enabling the extension).

The quick fix is to manually specify the `format` variable using `ScopedTypeVariables` and `TypeApplications` (or adding a `Proxy format` argument to `theMessage`).

```
play :: forall format m. Message format m => Synth format -> m -> IO ()
play (Synth name) msg =
    print $ name ++ " now sounds like " ++ theMessage @format msg
```

However, the `Message` class raises a red flag as a misuse of typeclasses.  It's not always bad, but whenever you see a class whose methods all have types like

```
:: a -> Foo
:: a -> Bar
```

i.e. they take a single `a` in contravariant position, it's likely that you don't need a typeclass at all.  It's often cleaner to transform the class into a data type, like so:

```
data Message format = Message { theMessage :: String }
```

wherein each method becomes a record field.  Then concrete types that you instantiated, such as your `MessageA`, get "demoted" to functions:

```
messageA :: String -> Message format
messageA msg = Message { theMessage = msg }
```

Whenever you would have passed an `a` with a `Message` constraint, just pass a `Message` instead.  `a` dissolves into nothingness.

After you do this factoring you might be noticing that a lot of what you have written is sort of tautological and unnecessary.  Good!  Remove it!

Comment: Thanks! With your help I [got it working](https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/vivid/blob/f5db4fdc7aa13a956adc734bf6ecd2a895cab373/learning/riddles/gadt-forget/close-to-vivid.hs). I made the class actually need to know about the `format` parameter, and I used ScopedTypeVariables. I didn't turn out to need TypeApplications (and indeed couldn't get it to work).

Answer (score 3):

When type checking code involving polymorphic bindings, the type inference engine creates fresh type variables for each use of the binding.

Here's a concrete example:

```
show () ++ show True
```

Now, we know that `show :: Show a => a -> String`. Above the first call to `show` chooses `a ~ ()`, the second one chooses `a ~ Bool`. Wait! That looks as a contradiction since `()` and `Bool` are distinct types, so they can not be both equal to `a`. Is that it?

Nah, it is not a contradiction... it looks clear that each call of `show` can make its choice of `a` independently. During type inference this is done, roughly, as follows.

For each call we generate a fresh type variable, by renaming universally quantified type variables in the polymorphic type at hand

```
-- for the first call
show :: Show a0 => a0 -> String
-- for the second call
show :: Show a1 => a1 -> String
```

Then, we simply pick `a0 ~ ()` and `a1 ~ Bool` and we are done. The user never realized that this was going on under the hood.

In case there is a type error, however, the freshly generated variables can be reported to the user, revealing a piece of the underlying inference algorithm. For instance

```
show []
```

Here, two polymorphic values are used, so we generate fresh variables for both.

```
[] :: [a0]
show :: Show a1 => a1 -> String
```

To typecheck, we need `a1 ~ [a0]`, so we end up with (after some context reduction, which does not matter now):

```
[] :: [a0]
show :: Show a0 => [a0] -> String
```

Good, we no longer have `a1` around. But what about `a0`? We do not have found any specific value for `a0`. Indeed, we can not do that, since the code does not contain anything to force that choice: `a0` remains an ambiguous type at the end.

This happens because `[]` can create a list of any type, while `show` can take a list of any type as input (as long as its element type is showable). But these constraints do not tell us what the type should be!

Concluding, the code is ambiguous, so we have to fix it by telling GHC what type we choose. Any of these would be fine

```
show ([] :: [Int])   -- choose a0 ~ Int
show ([] :: [Bool])  -- choose a0 ~ Bool
show ([] :: [Char])  -- choose a0 ~ Char
```

In your code

```
play :: Message format m => Synth format -> m -> IO ()
play (Synth name) msg =
  print $ name ++ " now sounds like " ++ theMessage msg
```

there is nothing which forces `theMessage msg` to use the same `format` which appears in the type of `play`. It is perhaps "obvious" to you that it should be, but it is not the only possible choice.

Choosing the same `format` is tricky here since your `class` has ambiguous types. This could still be used by turning on `TypeApplciations` and `AmbiguousTypes`, but something tells me that your design might be wrong, so I am a bit cautious here to suggest a solution. What you are trying to achieve? Why does the type of `the Message` not mention `format` in any way?

Comment: Thanks! With your help I [got it working](https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/vivid/blob/f5db4fdc7aa13a956adc734bf6ecd2a895cab373/learning/riddles/gadt-forget/close-to-vivid.hs). I made the class actually need to know about the `format` parameter, and I used ScopedTypeVariables. I didn't turn out to need TypeApplications (and indeed couldn't get it to work).